# VBA ListFillRange populate using dynamic range from different sheet

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I am trying to populate a combobox drop down list when a different combobox "combobox2" is clicked. I am receiving the error Runt time error 438 Object doesnt support this property or method. I am also sources the listfillrange values from a seperate worksheet. I have included my code below.

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Click()

     Dim N As Long

     N = Worksheets("Regions-Offices").Cells(1, 8).End(xlDown).Row

     ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = N

     Worksheets("Global").OLEObjects("ComboBox3").Object.ListFillRange = Worksheets("Regions-Offices").Range("H1:" & N).Address

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't have the 2nd H in the range

Comment: Also, you can use `offset` from `H1` instead of using `N` or offset `N`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I changed the range to be Range("H1:" & "H" & N) however now i am getting error 438 Object doesnt support this property or method

Comment: `range("h1:h" & n)` I would have tried.  Which line is the error on, just to be sure.  There are some arguments to `.address` too

Comment: @Nathan_Sav the error is on the following line "Worksheets("Global").OLEObjects("ComboBox3").Object.ListFillRange = Worksheets("Regions-Offices").Range("H1:H" & N).Address". Also evenb with Address removed error 438 is still there

Comment: The worksheet name isn't evaluated in the return of `address` so `'Regions-Offices'!H1:H" & N`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `External` parameter of `Address` property:

```
Worksheets("Global").OLEObjects("ComboBox3").ListFillRange = Worksheets("Regions-Offices").Range("H1:H" & N).Address(, , , True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The worksheet name isn't evaluated in the return of address so

`"'Regions-Offices'!H1:H" & N`